# Can I sort out my immigration/work visa during the time between flights in Canada?

Tags: visas, canada, work

I'm heading to Canada in January, flying from London to Kelowna, via a 6 hour stopover in Toronto.

I'm doing the IEC working holiday visa.

Does anyone know if it's possible to sort out all the paperwork during my time between flights, or do I have to do it at the final destination? Ideally, I'd like to use the stopover time productively so I can get out of the airport quicker at the end.

Comment: The vote to close this question as "opinion based" is puzzling.  The answer is a matter of fact, even if it neither "yes, it is possible" nor "no, it is not possible" but "in fact, it is required."

Answer (score 12):

You do not have a choice.  You will have to do all your immigration formalities in Toronto.  The flight from Toronto to Kelowna is a domestic flight, so you'll have to pass through immigration control before you get to the gate to board that flight.

Comment: Excellent, that makes it easy, 

 Thanks very much